# Skip whole Test Suite on Assert Failure in any Test

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, assertions

```
TestNG.xml ::

<suite name="Suite" preserve-order="true" parallel="false" verbose="1">
    <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="smokeTest.SmokeScenario01">
                <methods>
                    <include name="method1"/>                   
                    <include name="method2"/>
                </methods>
            </class>    
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

If Any Assert Fails under Method 1, then i need to skip the execution of Method 2 too.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a dependency from `method2` to `method1`:

```
@Test
public void method1() {
  // ...
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "method1")
public void method2() {
  // ...
}
```